# Powershell start-process error while calling Https url

Tags: windows, powershell, tidal-scheduler

I have suddenly started getting an error `Start-process : this command cannot run due to the error. no application is associated with the specified file for this operation`

Anything else I am missing here? It is the same cmd script that is running from last 2 months

Following is the command I am running from .CMD file.

> Powershell start-process https://my-url

Comment: I didn't get error message on command execution: `Powershell -nop -c "start-process https://web-site"`. Browser started with site opening.

Comment: Are you able to open the url using windows start -> run ? I am suspecting that there may not be a default browser ?

Comment: @Daemon-5 let me check adding -nop -c

Comment: @shahkalpeshp URL is accessible and default browser is IE, same command was running for last 2 months

Comment: Are you able to run `Powershell start-process https://my-url` using a separate command window but not as part of the batch file ?

Comment: @shahkalpeshp No, I can't run. Getting weird error for "screen resolution is too low for IE to run"

Comment: @Daemon-5 adding -nop -c did not work..

Comment: @MangeshSathe: I would suggest fixing that first. Based on my googling, it tells me that the display drivers are not up-to-date with OS update. Perhaps there was OS update or upgrade which could have caused this.

Comment: Command `Powershell start-process https://my-url` works. I think the error reason: you do not have [default browser](https://superuser.com/questions/578439/). Choose default apps for installed [web-browser.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_other-msedge_win10/web-browser-option-missing-under-default-apps-in/18da1c45-1d04-428b-8f97-003c7f14b8e7)

Comment: Is there anyway if I can run it in background without invoking any browser

Comment: You can run theese commands: `start msedge.exe https://my-url`;`start chrome.exe https://my-url`; etc. But without browser run `bitsadmin` utility by download-job usage. Or use `WinHttpRequest` object (by VBscript). There are alse external tools: `wget`, `curl`.